# jenkins space: how not to store all jars in all builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, diskspace

I have a couple jenkins builds that run every second hour or so, since jenkins stores the data and metadata for the builds this takes up a lot of space but most of that space goes to the jars that are stored.

Jenkins keeps every jar for every build and most of them don't really change from one build to another so I was wondering if there's a way to

a) store only the jars that changed, which would be the best case scenario, something using symbolic links or something;

b) don't store the jars at all, we don't really check the builds by using the jars as a debug tool so we don't really need them. Of course I could put a cron to erase them, but I'd prefer do that from inside jenkins if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins only stores jars and such if you have an "Archive the artifacts" post-build action in your job. If you don't have this, it doesn't archive anything except for logs and results.

If you're wanting to store SOME stuff but just not the jars, you can change the Excludes line in the advanced setting of the "Archive the artifacts" post-build action.

Comment: I don't have the archive the artifacts in any build: they are stored anyway.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm not sure what to tell you. In my installation, `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/MyJob/builds/4` only contains a dozen *.xml, *.html, etc. files, whereas `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/MyJob` contains all the source and built objects, but only for the most recent build. Where's all the artifcat history stored for you?